# ‘There are two bedrooms in each house’

Tags: each-every

If one has two bedrooms and the other has two bedrooms, isn’t ‘there are two bedrooms in each house’ valid?

I see someone said *there are two bedrooms in each house* even though one has one bedroom and the other has one bedroom.

Is it valid or a common mistake in English?

> "Price" is singular and "prices" is plural. For example: The price of
> coffee is high. **The prices for everything** are high.

It’s not for ‘each,’ but a related statement.

Comment: When said of two houses, "there are two bedrooms in each house" is only true if _both_ houses have two bedrooms.

Comment: But why do even native English speakers make the same mistake? Because are they confused with ‘all things’ and ‘everything’?

Comment: What mistake? Who says they do?

Comment: Actually based on the excerpt, I made the same mistake.

Comment: This is not a common mistake among native English speakers. It's pretty clear that 'in each' means both houses must have two bedrooms. The speaker in question is simply wrong or is trying to deceive someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one has two bedrooms and the other has two bedrooms, isn’t ‘there are two bedrooms in each house’ valid?

That's right. One house has two bedrooms, another house has two bedrooms, so they each have two bedrooms. There are four bedrooms in total.

> I see someone said there are two bedrooms in each house even though one has one bedroom and the other has one bedroom.

That's just wrong. It's not a common mistake either.

Comment: It answers my question, but could you explain about the ‘everything’ case? Thanks.

Comment: The word “everything" is a pronoun, but it is neither singular not plural. Instead, it is an indefinite pronoun. Indefinite pronouns, such as “everything", “everyone", “anyone", “anything", and “nothing" do require singular subject-verb agreement but that does not make them singular.

Comment: Then, the prices for everything is correct and the price for everything is incorrect?

Comment: Indefinite pronouns, such as “everything" require singular subject-verb agreement

Comment: I know but every thing is singular and everything is not singular It feels weird.

Comment: "Everything" is grammatically singular

Comment: But of course, "the prices for everything" is grammatically plural